# Where does GCC store compiled files?

Tags: gcc

when I make some source code for C/C++ and compile it, I get no errors from the
CMD, but I have no idea where the application has been stored.

Sorry if I sound stupid, but I just have no idea where they are! I've searched everywhere!

Comment: Normally, the object files or executables are placed in the current directory where the compiler is invoked. If you're at the command line, that's easy to find. If you're using an IDE, the IDE does it's best to hind them in as obscure a place as possible. There's probably rhyme and reason to its choice, but you have to find the documentation to know where it's put them and why (just one of the many reasons I don't use an IDE). However, this all adds up to "there isn't enough information in the question to be able to help you". We need to know what you're using, which platform you're on, etc.

Comment: It would also help to know what command line you executed (or your IDE executed).  You can usually specify the pathname of the object files that are created, or the pathname to the executable that's created.  But how depends on the compiler (on Unix-like systems, `-o outfile` usually names the output file from a compilation step).

Comment: Without the `-o outfilename` option, executable will be named `a.out` in the working directory.